# ImageMagick convert creates white output

Tags: svg, imagemagick, png, imagemagick-convert

I try to convert an svg to png with ImageMagick ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q8 under Windows 7 (64-bit)

I tried this code:

```
C:\>convert -monitor -define registry:temporary-path=D:\ sourceSVG.svg targetPNG.png
```

I use -define registry... because I dont have enough space in C:. There are no errors printed in the prompt but the output PNG is all white. There is not a single pixel in any other colour. The SVG seems to be correct, I could open it with IrfanView.

This is how the SVG looks (it has over 3500 polygons):

```
<svg height="40900" width="49500">
    <polygon points="15968.0,3603.0 15924.0,4238.0 16061.0,4234.0 16140.0,4203.0 16177.0,3661.0 15968.0,3603.0" style="fill:#FFFFA5;" />
    <polygon points="23738.0,5019.0 23738.0,5020.0 23739.0,5020.0 23739.0,5019.0 23738.0,5019.0" style="fill:#FFBD00;" />
</svg>
```

What could be the problem? Propably too much polygons right? But there wasn't any errors.. How can I fix this problem?

**Edit:** In order to find out where the problem lies a tried a couple of things:

1. I checked whether the problem is caused because of too many polygons. So I deleted all polygons but two. Still same problem
2. I checked whether the problem is cause because of the ".0" so I removed them to have Integers. Still same problem
3. I checked wether the problem is caused by a too big width/length. So I halved the width/length and made sure to delete all polygons wich lied beyond the new width/length ( ~24000 each). Still same problem. I halved them again (~12000 each) and one polygon was shown and the other one was missing (there were 2 polygons in the svg)

Comment: What are the height and width of the output file? What happens if you delete all but 5-10 lines in your input file?

Comment: the height and width of the output file are correct. Please take a look at the question I updated it.

Comment: I use ImageMagick 6.9.0-10 and it seems to work fine and produce an output image with 2 polygons as expected. I think you might do yourself a favour by making the polygons bigger and blacker till you get things debugged - a single yellow dot on a 40,000x40,000 canvas isn't the easiest to spot. Try upgrading your ImageMagick too.

Comment: it worked fine with height="40900" width="49500" for you? I installed also 6.9.0-10 but it still did not work. I tried with bigger polygons and with better colors but the output is still all white. Which "Q-build" did you use? Q16, Q8, Q4..? And what do you think the problem is? Is it because my memory/cpu is not big/good enough or is it a problem caused by ImageMagick?